# GWT AsyncCallback Does Not Populate Static Member

Tags: java, gwt, asynchronous, smartgwt

I have an `AsyncCallback` call that contacts my GWT-RPC service and retrieves some data. I am trying to store that data into a class which has a static method to store the results of the query. However, I noticed that the data is not being populated in the static data member. If I "slow down" the AsyncCallback call by putting an SC.logWarn(...) in the AsyncCallback call, then the static data member gets populated properly.

```java
final AsyncCallback<Set<MyData>> dataCallback =
         new AsyncCallback<Set<MyData>>() 
         {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Set<MyData> aDataType)
            {
               for (MyData data : aDataType)
               {
                  String someData = aDataType.getData();

                  Record rec = new Record();
                  rec.setAttribute("data", someData);
                  getDataSource().addData(rec);                  
               }                   
               LocalUiCache.setLocalCache(new ResultSet(getDataSource()));
            }
         };
      MyDataService.RPC.getInstance().getData(dataCallback);
```

...

```java
public class LocalUiCache
{
   private static ResultSet localCache;

   /**
    * @return the localCache
    */
   public static ResultSet getLocalCache()
   {
      return localCache;
   }

   /**
    * @param aLocalCache the localCache to set
    */
   public static void setLocalCache(ResultSet aLocalCache)
   {
      localCache = aLocalCache;
   }
}
```

Comment: might help : http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/ResultSet.html#addDataArrivedHandler%28com.smartgwt.client.data.events.DataArrivedHandler%29

Comment: @Sednus: I am doing that now, but the problem is where this code is executed to populate a control, it only calls onDataArrived when you click the ComboBox drop-down. So the user has to click the ComboBox drop down before the cache can be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure at this, but I suppose that SmartGWT doesn't reloads your changes fast.
You can try to tweak dataSource cache or call explicitly [invalidate](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/DataSource.html#invalidateCache%28%29) method.

Other suggestion will surely work, but it's 'dirty hack'. You can put in async callback scheduled call:

```
new Timer() {    
  public void run() {
    LocalUiCache.setLocalCache(new ResultSet(getDataSource()));
  }
}.schedule(50);
```